# Uploading package to pypi using twine: Invalid URI

Tags: python, pypi

I followed the [official documentation](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/distributing-packages/#uploading-your-project-to-pypi) for uploading packages to PyPI, as well as the information provided in PyPI readme, but I get a HTTP 400 error each time:

```
$ twine upload dist/*
Uploading distributions to https://upload.pypi.org/legacy
Enter your username: Sinistag
Enter your password:
Uploading paulla.check_dns_sync-0.1.dev0.py3-none-any.whl
HTTPError: 400 Client Error: home_page: Invalid URI for url: https://upload.pypi.org/legacy
```

What is going on ?

Comment: Same issue here. I just get a longer message saying the API has been deprecated. I imagine the PyPi API was upgraded and twine became obsolete. They just need to update the documentation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem was with the package url defined in `setup.py`

`Invalid URI` means the `url` field in the setup() function is not a valid url. It should be something like `url="https://github.com/namespace/repo"` for example

This is the url to the package code, and the new pypi repo doesn't accept package with wrong url.

see [this issue](https://github.com/pypa/twine/issues/258) on twine's repo