# Twine won't let me register or upload my package: is https://upload.pypi.org/legacy/ wrong?

Tags: python, package, pypi, twine

I have a [Python package](https://github.com/wpm/mycroft) that I am trying to register on PyPI. I am trying to do this with the latest version of twine (1.9.1) and following the [instructions on the twine webpage](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/twine).

I have my package correctly configured locally. (`setup.py` is complete and all that.) The name has not been claimed on PyPI. I have an account on PyPI. I don't have a  `~/.pypirc` file on my machine. I have built a source distribution and a wheel.

```
> ll dist
total 64
-rw-r--r--  1 billmcn  staff  14184 Aug  1 13:35 mycroft-1.1.0.tar.gz
-rw-r--r--  1 billmcn  staff  15996 Aug  1 13:36 mycroft-1.1.0-py3-none-any.whl
```

When I try to register either of these packages I get the following error message.

```
> twine register dist/mycroft-1.1.0.tar.gz 
Registering package to https://upload.pypi.org/legacy/
Enter your username: billmcn
Enter your password: 
Registering mycroft-1.1.0.tar.gz
HTTPError: 410 Client Error: Project pre-registration is no longer required or supported, so continue directly to uploading files. for url: https://upload.pypi.org/legacy/
```

I get the same error message when I try to register the wheel file. This makes me think this registration step is unnecessary. However, when I try to upload my packages I see this.

```
> twine upload dist/*
Uploading distributions to https://upload.pypi.org/legacy/
Enter your username: billmcn
Enter your password: 
Uploading mycroft-1.1.0-py3-none-any.whl
[================================] 23132/23132 - 00:00:00
HTTPError: 403 Client Error: You are not allowed to upload to 'mycroft'. for url: https://upload.pypi.org/legacy/
```

Which looks like the error you get if you have failed to register your packages before trying to upload them. I don't see my package when I [browse for it](https://pypi.python.org/pypi?%3Aaction=search&term=mycroft&submit=search) on the PyPI site. So I'm stuck.

That https://upload.pypi.org/legacy/ looks a little suspicious to me. Am I supposed to be specifying some other URL?

How do I register my package?

---

This looks similar to [Uploading package to pypi using twine: Invalid URI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44672358/uploading-package-to-pypi-using-twine-invalid-uri?rq=1). The issue there was that the person had an invalid `url` keyword argument in their `setup.py:setup` function. However, my URL is the project's github page, https://github.com/wpm/mycroft, and is correct.

I see the same problem if I have the following `~/.pypirc` file:

```
[distutils]
index-servers =
  pypi
  pypitest

[pypi]
username=billmcn
password=********

[pypitest]
username=billmcn
password=********
```

---

Various attempts to manually specify the upload URL.

```
twine upload dist/* -r https://pypi.python.org/pypi
KeyError: Missing 'https://pypi.python.org/pypi' section from the configuration file
or not a complete URL in --repository.
Maybe you have a out-dated '~/.pypirc' format?
more info: https://docs.python.org/distutils/packageindex.html#pypirc
```

The `--help` text says twine should be able to figure out whether I'm specifying a repository name or URL, but let's be explicit.

```
> twine upload dist/* --repository-url https://pypi.python.org/pypi
Uploading distributions to https://pypi.python.org/pypi
Note: you are uploading to the old upload URL. It's recommended to use the new URL "https://upload.pypi.org/legacy/" or to leave the URL unspecified and allow twine to choose.
Enter your username: billmcn
Enter your password: 
Uploading mycroft-1.1.0-py3-none-any.whl
HTTPError: 410 Client Error: Gone (This API has been deprecated and removed from legacy PyPI in favor of using the APIs available in the new PyPI.org implementation of PyPI (located at https://pypi.org/). For more information about migrating your use of this API to PyPI.org, please see https://packaging.python.org/guides/migrating-to-pypi-org/#uploading. For more information about the sunsetting of this API, please see https://mail.python.org/pipermail/distutils-sig/2017-June/030766.html) for url: https://pypi.python.org/pypi
```

So I should be using the "new" URL https://upload.pypi.org/legacy/?

```
> twine upload dist/* --repository-url https://upload.pypi.org/legacy/
Uploading distributions to https://upload.pypi.org/legacy/
Enter your username: billmcn
Enter your password: 
Uploading mycroft-1.1.0-py3-none-any.whl
HTTPError: 403 Client Error: You are not allowed to upload to 'mycroft'. for url: https://upload.pypi.org/legacy/
```

I'm stumped. And I can't find any official source for the current correct URL.

---

And I'd like to get twine working because the [Python documentation recommends against](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/distributing-packages/#uploading-your-project-to-pypi) using `python setup.py register` and `python setup.py upload`.

I tried this anyway and ran into what looks like the same problem.

```
> python setup.py register
running register
running egg_info
writing mycroft.egg-info/PKG-INFO
writing dependency_links to mycroft.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
writing entry points to mycroft.egg-info/entry_points.txt
writing requirements to mycroft.egg-info/requires.txt
writing top-level names to mycroft.egg-info/top_level.txt
reading manifest file 'mycroft.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
writing manifest file 'mycroft.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
running check
We need to know who you are, so please choose either:
 1. use your existing login,
 2. register as a new user,
 3. have the server generate a new password for you (and email it to you), or
 4. quit
Your selection [default 1]: 

Username: billmcn
Password: 
Registering mycroft to https://upload.pypi.org/legacy/
Server response (410): Project pre-registration is no longer required or supported, so continue directly to uploading files.
```

and

```
> python setup.py sdist bdist_wheel upload
...builds the packages...
running upload
Password: 
Submitting dist/mycroft-1.1.0.tar.gz to https://upload.pypi.org/legacy/
Upload failed (403): You are not allowed to upload to 'mycroft'.
error: Upload failed (403): You are not allowed to upload to 'mycroft'.
```

---

Opened PyPI [issue #677](https://github.com/pypa/pypi-legacy/issues/677).

Comment: Have you tried specifying the repository URL to twine? I believe you can do something like `twine upload dist/* -r https://pypi.python.org/pypi`

Comment: I tried a few variants of that to no avail. Modified the original post above.

Comment: I found your error message on https://packaging.python.org/guides/migrating-to-pypi-org/, but that doesn't really explain what's going on. I also took a look at https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/distributing-packages/#uploading-your-project-to-pypi but that appears to be what you are doing. At this point, I would try asking the people at PyPI. It sounds like something is broken.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sadly for you, even if it seems empty and doesn't have any code, it looks like there already is a 'mycroft' package on PyPI: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mycroft/0.1.0. That's why the api tells you that you don't have right over this package name.

It might come from an older version of pypi since it doesn't even have a default release. That's probably why it could not be found via the research tool. I were able to find it using the json api : https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mycroft/json

I don't know the politic of pypi over this, but maybe they can remove it since even the GitHub throw a 404. The package would probably not be accepted for upload with the new api anyway.

Comment: [Procedure for Transferring PyPI Name Ownership](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1elum7ENjQb0dLB4ATfYNtnXYVLUzsKacc0VWnHHJb2A/edit)